# How to retrieve build jobs in which 'Restrict where this project can be run' is NOT set?

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to retrieve a list of build jobs which were not explicitly assigned to a node/tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Label Linked Jobs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Label+Linked+Jobs+Plugin) will be able to do this. It will tell you about jobs tied to labels but also those that aren't ('label-less').